# WPF Unfreeze UI when showing heavy window

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface

I have heavy window (Devexpress UI), and, when I call window.Show() in my ICommand body, UI freezes. I want to show some progress while window loaded.
I was trying to call it in async method, but could not find any way to call Show in async way:

1. I was try Task.Run but it fail with exception of different UI threads.
2. I was try to call Application.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke but this also freezes UI.

Little adjustment:
I was wrong about Show() freezes. UI freeze at constructor call: var window = new ProductsPricesWindow()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible to make UI responsible when other UI component initialized.
So in my case solution is just allow UI to show in BusyIndicator (I use Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit) current state.
To do this I just put await Task.Delay(100); before creating window.

Also was helpful to pre-initialize creating window in background thread that starts on my app start. This makes creatng new window more responsible and even makes BusyIndicator live sometime.

```
    public void Init()
    {
        var thr = new Thread(
            async () =>
            {
                BusyContent = "Loading...";
                try
                {
                    // pre-init dx
                    await Application.Current.Invoke(
                       () =>
                       {
                           var window = new Views.ProductsPricesWindow();
                           window.Close();
                       }
                    );

                    ...
                }
                finally
                {
                    NotBusy();
                }
            }
        );
        thr.Name = nameof(Init);
        thr.Start();
    }

    public async Task AddProductsPrices(Window p)
    {
        try
        {
            BusyContent = "Loading...";
            await Task.Delay(100);
            var window = new ProductsPricesWindow();
            window.Show();
        }
        finally
        {
            NotBusy();
        }
    }
```

Application.Current.Invoke is extender:

```
    public async static Task Invoke(this Application app, Action action, DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.Normal)
    {
        if (app != null)
        {
            await app.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                priority,
                action
            );
        }
        else
            action();
    }
```

XAML

```
    <extToolkit:BusyIndicator
        IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
    >
        <extToolkit:BusyIndicator.BusyContent>
            <TextBlock 
                Text="{Binding BusyContent}" 
                FontSize="72"
            />
            <Grid>
                ...
            </Grid>
        </extToolkit:BusyIndicator.BusyContent>
   </extToolkit:BusyIndicator>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your execute some time-consuming work in another thread, then you must synchronize a result of another thread with UI thread. To synchronize two threads(new thread and UI thread), it is necessary to use [Dispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx).

[As MSDN says:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms741870(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Only one thread can modify the UI thread. But how do background
>   threads interact with the user? A background thread can ask the UI
>   thread to perform an operation on its behalf. It does this by
>   registering a work item with the Dispatcher of the UI thread. The
>   Dispatcher class provides two methods for registering work items:
>   Invoke and BeginInvoke. Both methods schedule a delegate for
>   execution. Invoke is a synchronous call – that is, it doesn’t return
>   until the UI thread actually finishes executing the delegate.
>   BeginInvoke is asynchronous and returns immediately.

For example:

xaml:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox"/>
```

in code-behind:

```
Task.Run(()=> {         
   Thread.Sleep(5000);//imitate time consuming work
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render,
            new Action(() => { 
                            textbox.Text="Hello World!:)"}));
});
```

In the above example, we create a new thread `(Task.Run(...))` and synchronize result of new thread with UI thread by calling Dispatcher`(Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...))`

**UPDATE:**

You should call new window on UI thread. So the code would be:

```
var yourWindow=new YourWindow();
yourWindow.ShowDialog();
```

However, as you did not show any code located in constructor of `YourWindow`, I try to suppose that there is some method which is time consuming. Then your code should look like this:

```
public class YourWindow()
{
     public YourWindow()
     {
         Task.Run(()=> {         
                   TimeConsumingMethod(); 
                   });
     }

     private void TimeConsumingMethod()
     {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);//imitate time consuming work
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render,
            new Action(() => { 
                            textbox.Text="Hello World!:)"}
     }
}
```

Comment: In my case I have "consuming work" is window.Show(). Devexpress grid takes a long time to load. This is UI-thread work and this is why I ask to help to call this in async way. If you read my question you will see that I already know about Application.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke and Task.Run.

Comment: @Sopholos please see my updated question. Feel free to ask any question

Comment: "I try to suppose that there is some method which is time consuming", yes, this method called InitializeComponent();

Comment: @Sopholos could you show some code? For example, constructor and XAML of your Windows. Is it MVVM application?

Comment: There is nothing special to show. This is just damn slow devexpress components. You could install their trial and see that window with grid will load much more time than usual. Without any data inside. just <Grid>
        <dxg:GridControl />
    </Grid> and window showed not momentally but for about 500ms. I does not need resolve devexpress speed. I need way to call UI without blocking UI for time UI created.

Comment: @Sopholos But what about of speed of opening of the first window? Is it slow to open the first window? what's the difference between the first window(e.g. MainWindow) and your opening Second Window?

Comment: First window does not contain dxgrid. I think this is just some internal initialization of themes/references/etc of devexpress grid. And first window have 1. default WPF splash window mechanic. 2. busycontent for internal mechanincs. so loading of app with first window is not a problem. problem is freezing UI on opening second window